# R: fitting Symmetric model

Tags: categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

I am trying to fit symmetric model using R. I saw a great [post](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/145) on how to conduct this model. However, it really bothers me why GLM still get result like chisquare, G^2 even if singularities occurs and one variable is NA. I guess the variable should be taken as Zero because it is exactly the intercept? Am I right here?

Besides, based on the background of Poisson distribution of Y. The degree of freedom of null deviance is 9 instead of 8. Do I miss something here?

```r
siskel=rep(c("con", "mixed", "pro"), c(3,3,3))
ebert=rep(c("con", "mixed", "pro"), 3)
count=c(24, 8, 13, 8, 13, 11, 10, 9, 64)

symm3=3*(siskel=="pro")*(ebert=="pro")
symm1=1*(siskel=="con")*(ebert=="con")
symm4=4*(siskel=="mixed")*(ebert=="con")+4*(siskel=="con")* 
        (ebert=="mixed")
symm6=6*(siskel=="con")*(ebert=="pro")+6*(siskel=="pro")* 
        (ebert=="con")
symm2=2*(siskel=="mixed")*(ebert=="mixed")
symm5=5*(siskel=="mixed")*(ebert=="pro")+5*(siskel=="pro")*
        (ebert=="mixed")

model = glm(count ~ siskel + ebert, family=poisson(link=log))
summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = count ~ symm1 + I(symm4/4) + symm6 + symm2 + symm5 + 
    symm3, family = poisson(link = log))

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9  
 0.0000   0.0000   0.4332   0.0000   0.0000   0.3112  -0.4525  -0.3217   0.0000  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.15888    0.12500  33.271  < 2e-16 ***
symm1       -0.98083    0.23936  -4.098 4.17e-05 ***
I(symm4/4)  -2.07944    0.27951  -7.440 1.01e-13 ***
symm6       -0.28609    0.04052  -7.061 1.66e-12 ***
symm2       -0.79697    0.15211  -5.239 1.61e-07 ***
symm5       -0.37126    0.05123  -7.246 4.28e-13 ***
symm3             NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 102.21480  on 8  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:   0.59276  on 3  degrees of freedom
AIC: 52.784

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: *"even if singularities occurs and one variable is NA"* glm will just remove the variable from the design matrix and fit the resulting model without singularity.